# making a div stay a certain distance from the bottom.

Tags: html, css

I'm playing around with overlapping elements by using negative margins. This caused an issue that has me kind of stumped. I want a box to stay a little bit above the bottom and change as the screen does. In the past I used a div to push things around but that isn't working for this.

The way I am thinking about doing it is to get the window size and adjust the margin-top. I can't seem to get it to work though (still a student). Anyhow I uploaded it so you could see what I was talking about. [www.purdyfx.com](http://www.purdyfx.com). Please let me know what you think, even if it's to call me stupid.

Comment: using the position and bottom keep it from the bottom of the element. I am trying to keep it a distance from the bottom of the window. I thought this had to be done with js.

Comment: This does not have to be done with javascript.  If you see my answer below you can position it absolutely and then specify bottom: 10px in the css which will always keep the element 10px from the bottom of the page.

Comment: ok, got it. I had to max height my main div to the size of the bg image. once I put a few rules into play, what you said worked perfect.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use absolute positioning like this

```
<div id="footer"></div>

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    background-color: red;    
    height: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CgcBc/

Answer (score 3):

You could look into implementing a Sticky Footer (similar to a sticky header, but that it's stuck to the bottom of the page instead).

Have you tried to use absolute positioning on the div?

```css
#bottomDiv{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

and your html:

```
<div id="bottomDiv">This is stuck on the bottom</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

use `position :absolute` it will work or give negative values as you did before :P